# redirecting a stream for the entire .bat file inside itself

Tags: batch-file

I've recently started working with .bat files, and I'm trying to redirect the output to a file.

I've found 2 options, so far:

1. `echo aaa > out.txt` - which sends the output of the single echo command to the specified file (can also be appended using `>>`)
2. calling the entire file from the cmd using `somefile.bat > out.txt` (which is actually similar to number 1, as it sends the output of the single command `somefile.bat` to `out.txt`)

What I'm looking for is something else - I'm trying to have a line in my file that sends all the output from that point forth to the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo this goes to screen
(
echo this line goes to the file
echo also this line and the ping-output
ping www.stackoverflow.com
echo and this
)>file.txt
echo this goes to screen again
```

Note:

all inside the block (between `(` and `)`) is parsed at once. If you use variables inside the block, you may need delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal solution. It depends of the batch file requirements.

For a lot of batch files, the answer from Stephan will work without problems, taking in consideration what he pointed: all the code is inside a block and any variable management inside it may require delayed expansion.

Other alternative is to move the code under a subroutine, calling it with the redirection

```
@echo off
    call :mainProcess %* > outputFile
    exit /b

:mainProcess
    :: here the batch file begins
    echo %1 %2 %3
```

Comment: I like this, because it meets very exact "...have a line in my file that sends all the output from that point forth..." (although it is three lines ^^) - and no need for delayed expansion.

Comment: I also liked this, but it seemed more of an organization of Stephan's answer and the calling a batch file than something new.
But it's a great answer, and very clear